# Loading sql database in datatable

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dataview

```
Dim myTable As New DataTable("Freddy")
Dim view As New DataView(myTable)
Public Class Myform

Private Sub MyForm
 With myTable
        .Columns.Add("Check", GetType(Boolean))
```

I know it may seem weird but how can i edit the above code to add my sql db keeping the CHECK column i added using code?

```
 Dim sql As String = "Select Name,Gender,[Phone number] from Employee"
```

All i said might seem very weird but i need this for a purpose !

Comment: It's not weird, but i don't have an idea what you are trying to do

Comment: You can add a Bool column to the results via your SQL statement.  The DBProvider will fill in the datatable for you.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: why are you trying to keep a "check" column? what is the purpose of that column

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to send an [`ALTER TABLE` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/add-columns-to-a-table-database-engine) to the server using ADO.Net. The .Net `DataTable` object can't do this for you.